# Is there a way to access Smartsheets Workspace Attachments via API (not attached to any smartsheets but only to workspace)

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

I am looking to access attachments at a workspace level of a smartsheet. They are not attached to any smartsheets but attached to the root of a workspace only. Is there a way we can access these objects via API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is not possible through the Smartsheet API quite yet. While I can't give you a specific date that feature will be available, I did confirm that it is on the feature backlog and will make it into the API at a later date.